# How to get message id using Outlook API?

Tags: php, email, outlook-restapi

I am trying to retrieve email from Outlook API, but I want to display message id and other custom headers.

Here is the code:

```
$headers = array(
    "User-Agent: php-tutorial/1.0",
    "Authorization: Bearer ".token()->access_token,
    "Accept: application/json",
    "client-request-id: ".makeGuid(),
    "return-client-request-id: true",
    "X-AnchorMailbox: ". get_user_email()
);
$top = 2;
$skip = isset($_GET["skip"]) ? intval($_GET["skip"]) : 0;
$search = array (
    // Only return selected fields
    "\$select" => "Subject,ReceivedDateTime,Sender,From,ToRecipients,HasAttachments,BodyPreview",
    // Sort by ReceivedDateTime, newest first
    "\$orderby" => "ReceivedDateTime DESC",
    // Return at most n results
    "\$top" => $top, "\$skip" => $skip
);
$outlookApiUrl = $_SESSION["api_url"] . "/Me/MailFolders/Inbox/Messages?" . http_build_query($search);
$response = runCurl($outlookApiUrl, null, $headers);
```

What should I added in search?

Comment: What have you done on your own so far? Have you already checked API documentation?

Comment: @AntonTkachov I have checked document, currently I am able to get subject,to,form field.